# bash prevent escaping with echo

Tags: linux, bash, escaping, echo

I am relatively new to linux and am trying to create a TikZ figure parsing a file. In order to do so I read in the file with a $%&-bash script containing the following statement

```
echo "\fill[color=blue] ($xp,$zp) circle (5pt);" >> $fout
```

this results in the following  output

```
^Lill[color=blue] ($xp,$zp) circle (5pt);
```

Obviously echo escapes the \f and I did not find a way around it.
I have tried all options like "-e" "-n" and what have you, have tried all kinds of combinations of " ' etc, but to no avail.

I am stuck as so often with linux, but this time even google didn't help (OMG=Oh My Google!!!!!!!!).

Comment: can use printf as an alternative. all the usual escape characters can be used with printf

Comment: great, this works, (printf "\\\fill" did the trick). You saved my day, I really appreciate your help, best Enzo.

Comment: nw. glad it helped ;)

Comment: Are you sure you're using `bash`? The output you observe is consistent with the POSIX standard, which the built-in `echo` in  `dash` (the default shell in Ubuntu and some other distributions) adheres to.

Answer (score 3):

`echo` should not do backslash escapes by default, unless `-e` is specified. You can try `echo -E` to force turning them off (in case you have aliased `echo` to `echo -e` or something).

Alternatively, try using single quotes (although now that I think about it, I don't see how it would help):

```
echo '\fill[color=blue] ('"$xp,$zp"') circle (5pt);' >> $fout
```